# Stop a moving image in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

Im pretty new to the canvas element in HTML5.

What i want to do is move an image from the right hand side of the screen to the left, once it reaches the left i want it to begin again from the right hand side. I only want it to do this maybe 2/3 times and then stop.

I tried to add in a for loop so that it would limit the iterations but this was unsuccessful.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Heres my code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas> 
 <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var
    img = new Image,
    ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

  img.src = 'pies.png';
  img.addEventListener('load', function () {

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var x = 650, y = 194;

      return function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);

        x -= 1;
        if (x < -500) {
          x = 650;
        }
      };
    }(), 1000/40);
  }, false);
}, false);


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way is to specify a maximum number of leftward moves:**

```
// allow leftward moves = 2 1/2 time the canvas width 
// (plus an allowance for the image width)

var maxMoves = (canvas.width+image.width) *2.5;
```

**Then just countdown maxMoves until zero.  At zero, stop your animation:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';

var currentX=cw;
var delay=16; // 16ms between moves
var continueAnimating=true;
var nextMoveTime,maxMoves;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png";
function start(){

  maxMoves=(cw+img.width)*2.5;

  nextMoveTime=performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}


function animate(currentTime){

  if(continueAnimating){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

  if(currentTime<nextMoveTime){return;}

  nextMoveTime=currentTime+delay;
  
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(img,currentX,50);

  if(--currentX<-img.width){ currentX=cw; }

  if(--maxMoves<0){continueAnimating=false;}

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<p>Stop animating after 2 1/2 "sunrises"</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```